# Can this be a probability density function?

Tags: probability

$$
f(x) := \frac{1}{c} \exp((x-\mu)^T A (x-\mu)), \quad  x, \mu \in \mathbb{R}^k, A \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times k},
$$
where $c$ is the normalization factor for $\int_{\mathbb{R}^k} f(x) dx = 1$.

We know that $f$ will be a density function for a normal distribution, if $A$ is symmetric and negative definite.

Can $f$ be a probability density function of some probability distribution, if

- $A$ is symmetric, but positive definite?
- $A$ is not symmetric?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First question:

No. If $A$ is positive definite, then for all $x$, you have $x^TAx>0$, meaning $f(x) > 1$ for all $x\in \mathbb R^k$, meaning the integral will explode.

Second question: Yes, so long as $x^T A x < 0$ for all $x$.

Comment: Thanks! In the second question, if $f$ is a probability density function, must it be the one of a normal distribution?